# Artifactory Key metrics and Alertin

Tags: alert, artifactory, metrics

**Our setup:**
Our Artifactory servers are installed on Linux with Nginx proxy as front end. We use load balancer that simply redirect traffic to Nginx in a round robin fashion. We have Artifactory version 7.37.x

**Question**
What are recommendations based on best practices and field experience for monitoring and alerting Artifactory (a Java application)?

The reason for asking as we have many complaints from users about slow PUT and GET operations which results in build failures?
Based on the complaints by the time we get to the log files the request has either already completed and shows large value of latency in artifactory-requests, etc logs or has timed out with http response 503.

Our goal is to know these types of issues as soon as possible e.g. when a thread start to take long time send alert and initiate a thread-dump for analysis. This is one example and there could be many more issues and associated key KPI that we want to be alerted proactively.

So seeking experts to provide list of key metrics and alerting on them.

Answer (score -2):

Receiving a 503 error from Artifactory indicates that the server is temporarily unavailable due to being overloaded or undergoing maintenance. A 503 Service Unavailable error is an HTTP status code that indicates the server cannot handle the request at the moment. Here are some steps you can take to address and troubleshoot this issue:

1. **Check Artifactory Status Page:**
   Many services, including Artifactory, maintain a status page that provides real-time updates about server status and ongoing issues. Visit Artifactory's official status page or any communication channels they provide to check if there are known outages or maintenance periods.
2. **Monitor Server Resources:**
   Monitor the server's CPU, memory, and disk usage. If the server is consistently operating at or near its capacity, it might lead to 503 errors. Scale your server resources accordingly to handle the expected load.
3. **Review Logs:**
   Check the Artifactory logs for any error messages or warnings. The logs can provide insights into the underlying issues causing the 503 errors.
4. **Database Health:**
   Artifactory relies on a database for storing metadata and configuration. If the database is experiencing issues, it can lead to service disruptions. Ensure that the database server is healthy and responsive.
5. **Connection Pools:**
   Make sure your connection pools are configured appropriately. If you are exhausting available connections, it can lead to service unavailability. Adjust connection pool settings as needed.
6. **Reverse Proxy Configuration:**
   If you're using a reverse proxy (e.g., Nginx, Apache) in front of Artifactory, check its configuration. Misconfigured proxy settings can lead to connectivity issues.
7. **Load Balancing:**
   If you're using multiple instances of Artifactory behind a load balancer, ensure that the load balancer is properly distributing traffic and not overloading any specific instance.
8. **Application Performance Monitoring (APM):**
   Consider using APM tools to monitor the performance of your Artifactory instance. These tools can provide insights into slow requests, high response times, and other performance-related issues.
9. **Upgrade Artifactory:**
   Ensure that you're running the latest stable version of Artifactory. Newer versions often include bug fixes and performance improvements.
10. **Throttle or Retry Requests:**
    If the 503 errors are due to temporary spikes in traffic, consider implementing a retry mechanism for failed requests or adding throttling to limit the number of simultaneous requests.
11. **Contact Support:**
    If you've exhausted your troubleshooting options and the 503 errors persist, reach out to JFrog's support team for assistance. They can provide guidance based on your specific environment and configuration.

Remember that diagnosing and resolving 503 errors might require a combination of the above steps. It's important to have a systematic approach and to collaborate with your team to identify and address the root cause of the issue.